# Algorithm Basic Recursion - search in an array

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have a lot of trouble with recursion, including the logic behind it. I know that in principle every time we have a loop we can replace it with a call to the function. So I tried a simple example, and very classic, search for the maximum in a table. Here is the classic example of an iteration in java:

```
static void rechercheMax(int unTab []) {
    int max = unTab[0];

    for (int j = 0; j < unTab.length; j++) {
        if (unTab[j] > max) {
            max = unTab[j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the  max is " + max);
}
```

As you can see, nothing exceptional. On the other hand, where it gets much harder, is the recursive version that I made:

```
static int rechercheMaxRec(int[] unTab, int j, int max) {   
    if (j < unTab.length) {
        if (unTab[j] > max) {
            max = unTab[j];
            j++;
            rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);
        }else {
            j++;
            rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);             
        }
    } 
    return max;
}
```

Where I am completely lost, and it's really a "crazy" thing, is that once the end of the loop is reached, the counter starts in the opposite direction. Honestly, I do not understand, not at all.

When I call my function from the main it is done as follows

```java
// the call from the main..... there is of course code preceding this:
int unTab [] = {7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 103, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
System.out.println ("The max in the recursive is" + searchMaxRec (unTab, 0,0));
```

Could you explain to me two things?

- why does it not give the right result, and
- why is it going in the opposite direction?

This behaviour is quite unsettling to me; I fear I haven't understood anything about recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It does not give the right result because you forgot to use the value that the recursive call returns. You should in fact assign it to `max` (so it gets returned by the last statement in your function), or just return it immediately.

It (also) goes in the opposite direction because that is the *backtracking* part of recursion: first it dives into the deeper recursion levels (forward) and then it reaches the deepest point (when the `if` condition is no longer true) and starts returning from then end to the start. It is the principle of a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). It is first-in-last-out (FILO) order of processing. So in the "in" part (recursing) you get the forward-order, and in the "out" part (backtracking) you get the opposite order.

Note that you don't really need to make changes to variables in your code, like `j++` or `max =`. You can just pass the altered values directly as arguments to the recursive call:

```
static int rechercheMaxRec(int[] unTab, int j, int max) {   
    if (j < unTab.length) {
        if (unTab[j] > max) {
            return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j+1, unTab[j]);
        }else {
            return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j+1, max);             
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

You can even remove the inner `if / else` switch (which only makes a difference for the final argument) and use a `Math.max` expression instead:

```
static int rechercheMaxRec(int[] unTab, int j, int max) {   
    if (j < unTab.length) {
        return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j+1, Math.max(max, unTab[j])); 
    }
    return max;
}
```

Even that can be reduced with the help of a ternary operator:

```
static int rechercheMaxRec(int[] unTab, int j, int max) {   
    return j < unTab.length ? rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j+1, Math.max(max, unTab[j])) : max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Re "why does it not give the right result"**:

With recursion, you make the initial recursive call, which itself makes the second call, etc. The initial call will return the result returned from the nested call, which itself returns the result returned from its nested call, etc.

The reason your call here does not return the right result is that you call `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 0, 0);`, which *calls* `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);`, but does not *return its result*. So what happens is when you call `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 0, 0);`, it evaluates `if (j < unTab.length)` to `true`, then evaluates `if (unTab[j] > max)` to `true`, then runs `max = unTab[j];` (ie sets `max` to 7), then *calls* `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 1, 7);` but doesn't *return* the value returned by `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 1, 7);`. As a result, after *calling* `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 1, 7);`, the code exits the conditional block and calls `return max;`, ie returns 7.

So, basically what you want to is replace `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);` with `return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);`. This will return 103 instead of 7.

There's one other problem that doesn't affect your ability to just find the max of `untab`, but could cause other problems if you added more to the code. `untab` is of length 18, so if j == 17, your code will increment j and then call `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, 18, max);`, which is out of range. Again, that won't cause errors with your code as is, but if for example you tried to `System.out.println(...)` the value of `untab[j]`, it would throw an error.

The way you can avoid this is after incrementing `j`, check again if `j < unTab.length`, if so call `rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max)`, and if not then just return `max` since you're at the end of the array.

So here's the code that solves both problems:

```
static int rechercheMaxRec(int[] unTab, int j, int max) {
    if (j < unTab.length) {
        if (unTab[j] > max) {
            max = unTab[j];
            j++;
            if (j < unTab.length) {
                return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);
            } else {
                return max;
            } 
        }else {
            j++;
            if (j < unTab.length) {
                return rechercheMaxRec(unTab, j, max);
            } else {
                return max;
            }       
        }
    } 
    return max;
}
```

**Re: why is it going in the opposite direction?**:

I don't think it does :) I think it might have appeared as though it did because it returned 7 instead of 103, but that's just because of the concept of calling vs returning as discussed above.

Let me know if anything is not clear!

Comment: Thx very much for your precious comments and advice. I was not available during the last days. Just now. The problem was solved, nevertheless, I still have many difficulties to understand the recursion. Do you know any book, or websites where I can do more exercises. Thx for any help.